# why is the inverse image defined by the right kan extension instead of the left?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Why don't we define the inverse image of a sheaf to be the left kan extension and then take the sheafification?

Answer (score 1):

This construction mixes left and right adjoints, so has no universal property in general. This gives a theoretical justification of why people considered the usual construction first.

Comment: so, the principle of defining the inverse image is the one made to be adjoint to the direct image?

Comment: Ahistorically, yes, you could say that.

Comment: however, why we want the direct image to be a "right"adjoint functor instead of the left one? only after understanding that, we can define the inverse image to be its left adjunction.

Comment: The direct image can't be a left adjoint. Adjoints are very special among all functors, even before you choose an adjoint. For instance, if the direct image had a right adjoint then it would be right exact, and there would be no such thing as sheaf cohomology.